# Send summary email from a form with wp_mail

Tags: php, custom-post-types, forms, email, wp-mail

I'm trying to send two emails (one to the site manager and one to the user) with the data entered in a contact form made by me and placed in a wordpress template, but this doesn't work.
i am using wp_mail to send the fields
this is the form, which is located in a template file in /wp-content/themes/theme-child/page-template

```php
<form action ="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" class="steppers-content" aria-live="polite" id="justValidateForm" method="post">
                                <div class="it-page-sections-container">
                                    <section class="it-page-section" id="applicant">
                                        <div class="cmp-card mb-40">
                                            <div class="card has-bkg-grey shadow-sm p-big">
                                            <div class="card-header border-0 p-0 mb-lg-30">
                                                <div class="d-flex">
                                                <h2 class="title-xxlarge mb-0">
                                                    Richiedente
                                                </h2>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-body p-0">
                                                <div class="form-wrapper bg-white p-4">
                                                <div class="form-group cmp-input mb-0">
                                                    <label class="cmp-input__label" for="name">Nome*</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control mt-4" id="name" name="name" required/>
                                                    <div class="d-flex">
                                                    <span class="form-text cmp-input__text">Inserisci il tuo nome</span>
                                                </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group cmp-input mb-0">
                                                    <label class="cmp-input__label" for="surname">Cognome*</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname" required/>
                                                    <div class="d-flex">
                                                    <span class="form-text cmp-input__text">Inserisci il tuo cognome</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group cmp-input mb-0">
                                                    <label class="cmp-input__label" for="email">Email*</label>
                                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required />
                                                    <div class="d-flex">
                                                    <span class="form-text cmp-input__text">Inserisci la tua email</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </section>
                                    <section class="it-page-section" id="request">
                                        <div class="cmp-card mb-40">
                                            <div class="card has-bkg-grey shadow-sm p-big">
                                            <div class="card-header border-0 p-0 mb-lg-30">
                                                <div class="d-flex">
                                                <h2 class="title-xxlarge mb-0" id="request">Richiesta</h2>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-body p-0">
                                                <div class="form-wrapper bg-white p-4">
                                                <div class="select-wrapper mb-40 mt-4 bg-transparent p-0">
                                                    <label for="category" class="">Categoria di servizio*</label>
                                                    <select id="category" class="bg-transparent form-control" name="category" required>
                                                        <option selected="selected" value="">Seleziona categoria</option>
                                                        <?php foreach ($categorie_servizio as $categoria) {
                                                            echo '<option value="'.$categoria->term_id.'">'.$categoria->name.'</option>';
                                                        } ?>
                                                    </select>
                                                    <div class="d-flex">
                                                    <span class="form-text cmp-input__text">Seleziona la categoria del servizio per cui vuoi richiedere assistenza</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="select-wrapper p-big bg-transparent p-0">
                                                    <label for="service" class="">Servizio*</label>
                                                    <select id="service" class="bg-transparent form-control" name="service" required >
                                                        <option selected="selected" value="">
                                                            Scegli il servizio
                                                        </option>
                                                    </select>
                                                    <div class="d-flex">
                                                    <span class="form-text cmp-input__text">
                                                        Seleziona il servizio per cui vuoi richiedere assistenza</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="cmp-text-area p-0 mt-40">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="description" class="d-block">Dettagli*</label>
                                                    <textarea class="text-area form-control" id="description" rows="2" name="description" required ></textarea>
                                                    <span class="label">Inserire massimo 600 caratteri</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </section>
                                    <div class="privacy-wrapper">
                                        <p class="text-paragraph mb-3">
                                        Per i dettagli sul trattamento dei dati personali consulta l’
                                        <a href="#" class="t-primary">informativa sulla privacy.</a>
                                        </p>
                                        <div class="form-check mb-2">
                                        <div class="checkbox-body d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="privacy" name="privacy-field" value="privacy-field" required/>
                                            <label class="title-small-semi-bold pt-1 mb-0" for="privacy"
                                            >Ho letto e compreso l’informativa sulla privacy</label>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cmp-nav-steps">
                                        <nav class="steppers-nav" aria-label="Step">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm steppers-btn-prev p-0" >
                                            <svg class="icon icon-primary icon-sm" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <use href="#it-chevron-left"></use>
                                            </svg>
                                            <span class="text-button-sm t-primary">Indietro</span>
                                        </button>
                                        <!-- <button
                                            type="submit"
                                            class="btn btn-primary btn-sm steppers-btn-confirm send"
                                            data-bs-validate="validate"
                                            name="submit"
                                            formmethod="post"
                                        > -->
                                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contact_form">
                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm steppers-btn-confirm send" value="Submit" data-bs-validate="validate">
                                            <!-- <span class="text-button-sm">Invia</span> -->
                                            <svg class="icon icon-white icon-sm">
                                            <use href="#it-chevron-right" ></use>
                                            </svg>
                                        <!-- </button> -->
                                        </nav>
                                        <div id="alert-message" class="alert alert-success cmp-disclaimer rounded d-none" role="alert">
                                        <span
                                            class="d-inline-block text-uppercase cmp-disclaimer__message">Richiesta salvata con successo</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

this is my `functions.php`.

```php
// invio email per modulo di richiesta assistenza 
function prefix_send_email_to_admin() {
    
        $ra_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']);
        $ra_surname = sanitize_text_field($_POST['surname']);
        $ra_email = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);
        $ra_category = sanitize_text_field($_POST['category']);
        $ra_service = sanitize_text_field($_POST['service']);
        $ra_description = sanitize_textarea_field($_POST['description']);
        $to = $ra_email; 
        $subject = "Richiesta assistenza da sito ";
        $message = "'.$ra_name.'";
        //$content_type = function() { return 'text/html'; };
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8','From: My Site Name <support@example.com>');
        //add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', $content_type );
        
        wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    
}
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_contact_form', 'prefix_send_email_to_admin' );
add_action( 'admin_post_contact_form', 'prefix_send_email_to_admin' );
```

Are there any other better or easier ways to do this?
I also configured the easy wp smtp plugin and I receive the test emails correctly

The fields are also saved in custom post type which works fine, I just miss sending the emails.

**UPDATE FOR DEBUGGING**

To test I moved the php function to retrieve the data and send the email within the same file as the form (assistance.php) and I changed it like this.

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    echo "form sent!"  ;
    $ra_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']);
    $ra_surname = sanitize_text_field($_POST['surname']);
    $ra_email = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);
    $ra_category = sanitize_text_field($_POST['category']);
    $ra_service = sanitize_text_field($_POST['service']);
    $ra_description =  sanitize_textarea_field($_POST['description']);
    $to = $ra_email;
    $subject = "Richiesta assistenza da sito ";
    $message = "'.$ra_name.'";
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8','From: My Site Name <support@example.com>');

        //add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', $content_type );
       $sent = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
       if($sent) {
        echo "message sent! "  ;    
      }}
      else  {
        echo "message non inviato a" ; 
        $to = "example@email.com";
        $subject = "email di test ";
        $message = "email di test ";
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8','From: My Site Name <support@example.com>');
        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );     
      }
```

of course every page load I get an email, but at least I know emails work! so the problem is that it doesn't receive the data, in fact it doesn't even receive the sending.
how should i set the action attribute to stay if the function is in the same page? other ways to check if it receives "submit"?
I tried [these things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002424/php-post-not-working) but didn't fix it. The form also uses js, jquery and ajax, but in other files, it uses them to save the data entered in the form in a custom post type, show messages if the fields have been saved or not and to show the services depending on that category has been selected in the form. I hope this information can enlighten you because I'm running out of ideas, thanks

Comment: have you been able to isolate which part is not working? I'm not seeing any error checking, are you just running it and then looking for the email at the end? I don't see anything checking the value `wp_mail` returns to see if it's an error, e.g. if it returned `false`how would you know? It could be that the function isn't running, have you confirmed code in `prefix_send_email_to_admin` actually runs? And that the variables have the values you expected them to have? It's possible that they did get sent but were trashed as spam due to their contents. There's also no site manager recipient

Comment: @TomJNowell yes I did some tests before, how can I do to test it more accurately?  the emails is not sending them even in spam in my opinion it is not receiving the values ​​of the inputs, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.  Yes, now I have removed the manager's email because I wanted to try just one to try to understand why it doesn't work

Comment: Instead of sending an email, have you tried printing out all the values or logging them to the error log or a file? For all we know the error log is full of messages about trying to use POST variables that don't exist. Right now your `admin-post.php` gives no feedback of any kind, no output or `echo` statements, no redirects which means no useful information, it just runs the code and assumes every line is successful. It's also possible the email did send, but was trashed before it reached your inbox enroute as spam, so it never arrived, eitherway there's almost no info to debug with here

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you for the support, yes I tried to print them with echo, but it gives me undefined value, how do you record them in the debug log in a file?  yes exactly the debug contains that message.  I installed a plug-in called WP email login which logs all emails sent even the one with errors, but nothing results this makes me think it's not sending them because it doesn't receive the parameters from $POST but I don't understand

Comment: can you edit the code in your question to include that? It's hard to grasp exactly what you tried from a description, but much easier to see it firsthand, e.g. where and how you tried that. Additionally, can you confirm this is a normal form submission and not an AJAX submission? There's no JS code here but if there were it would open up several possibilities of finding the problem. Also, it's still really bad to not give any output, even a "success" would be super helpful by confirming the function ran

Comment: yes, as soon as I get back to the office, I'll add the code.  the module also uses Ajax and JS to save the values ​​in a custom post type and to show the services available after choosing the category, now I simplified it to do the tests by removing a lot but it doesn't work anyway.  i will try to get an output.

Comment: the function `sanitize_textarea` doesn't exist (in WP 6.3 at least). Maybe you just get an error for the undefined function. To sanitize a textarea you should use [`sanitize_textarea_field`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_textarea_field/)

Comment: how can I modify it to check if the function is executed or not?

Comment: ` if( isset($_POST['submit'] ) ){ echo 'email inviata';}else {echo 'email non invitata';} `I added this for testing but it always gives me unsent email. the submit doesn't even arrive, I moved the function to the same file as the form what should I put in action="" ?
and in input type submit ?

Comment: @TomJNowell I added some information and my tests could you, help me please?

Comment: You mentioned javascript but have not edited any javascript into your question, there's a very real possibility that `POST` is not working because you're using something like `jQuery.get(` to submit the form or some other JS based mistake. I also don't see any evidence that `prefix_send_email_to_admin` is running in your question

Comment: Thanks, I didn't put the JS because it's in other files and I didn't know it would cause problems.  In the other files I didn't find any jQuery.get(), but if it was something like this could it be worked around with PHP or is it necessary to modify jQuery?  I didn't do it, I'm modifying it to send the emails.  I put one of the last tests where I removed the function to do the same outside.  I found a file that fetches the form data to save it in the custom post type using `$params = json_decode(json_encode($_POST), true);
 ` ... could I put wp_email at the end of the whole function?